# Making a form field compulsory only for specific users

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

Is it possible to make a form field, in a template, compulsory, or non compulsory, for specific user? I have a field which I'd like to be compulsory for everyone but the administrator.

My understanding is that it is not possible, since the `null=False, blank=False` in the `model.py` is valid for all the instances of the field. Am I wrong?

**Edit - adding code**

models.py

```
class Work(models.Model):
    [...]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) # max_length = required
    [...]

class Event(models.Model):
    [...]
    repertoire = models.ManyToManyField(Work, blank=True)
    [...]
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Work, Event
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            [...]
            'repertoire',
            [...]
                    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from .forms import EventForm,
@never_cache
def event_create_view(request):
    active_user = request.user
    form_event = EventForm(request.POST or None, initial={'submitted_by' : active_user.profile.id})

    if request.method == "POST" and form_event.is_valid():

        this_event = form_event.save()
        return redirect('event-edit', id=this_event.id)

    else:
        messages.error(request, form_event.errors)

    context = {
            'form_event': form_event,
            }
```

template.html

```
<form id="eventForm" action='.' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>
[...]
{{ form_event.repertoire }}
[...]
    <input class="button" type='submit' value='Continue ->' />

</form>
```

Comment: For the model yes, but you can alter the form to make it compulsory for certain users. Can you share (relevant parts) of your model, view and form?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, I've added the code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the field required for certain users. For example by adding an extra parameter:

```
from .models import Work, Event

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            # …
            'repertoire',
            # …
        ]
    def __init__(self, *args, repertoire_required=True, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['repertoire'].required = repertoire_required
```

In the view, we then specify the parameter, based on the fact if the logged in user is for example an `is_admin`:

```
from .forms import EventForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@never_cache
@login_required
def event_create_view(request):
    active_user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_event = EventForm(
            request.POST,
            repertoire_required=not active_user.is_superuser,
            initial={'submitted_by' : active_user.profile.id }
        )
        if form_event.is_valid():
            this_event = form_event.save()
            return redirect('event-edit', id=this_event.id)
        else:
            messages.error(request, form_event.errors)
    else:
        form_event = EventForm(
            request.POST,
            repertoire_required=not active_user.is_superuser
        )
    context = {
        'form_event': form_event,
    }
    # …
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's so neat and makes sense. One additional question if you don't mind: what's the difference between using `form_event = EventForm(request.POST or None` (my form) versus `if request.method == 'POST': form_event = EventForm [...] else` (your form)?

Comment: @HBMCS: `request.POST or None` will pass `None` if `request.POST` is an *empty* `QueryDict`. But that does not per se means it is not a `POST` request, since some `POST` requests can be empty. I wrote a writeup some months ago about this: https://github.com/hapytex/django-antipatterns/blob/master/antipatterns/do_not_use_request_post_or_none.md